# Получение полных данных о смене статуса в JIRA при помощи Python библиотеки

Tags: python, jira, jira-api

Пытаюсь получить данные по каждой смене статуса в JIRA тикете при помощи библиотеки https://jira.readthedocs.io/index.html

Судя по документации к библиотеке, за данные о смене статуса это отвечает метод transitions.
Пытаюсь выполнить:

```
transitions = jira.transitions('BO-623', expand="changelog")
for v in transitions:
    print(v)
```

И получаю ответ без информации о предыдущем статусе и без инфы о дате/времени смены статуса.

```
{'id': '31', 'name': 'To Do', 'to': {'self': 'https://my.jira.server.com/rest/api/2/status/10007', 'description': '', 'iconUrl': 'https://my.jira.server.com/images/icons/statuses/open.png', 'name': 'To Do', 'id': '10007', 'statusCategory': {'self': 'https://my.jira.server.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2', 'id': 2, 'key': 'new', 'colorName': 'blue-gray', 'name': 'To Do'}}}
{'id': '51', 'name': 'Done', 'to': {'self': 'https://my.jira.server.com/rest/api/2/status/10005', 'description': 'Status indicates that this task has been completed..', 'iconUrl': 'https://my.jira.server.com/images/icons/statuses/closed.png', 'name': 'Done', 'id': '10005', 'statusCategory': {'self': 'https://my.jira.server.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/3', 'id': 3, 'key': 'done', 'colorName': 'green', 'name': 'Done'}}}
```

Помогите с решением - как с помощью этой библиотеки получить информацию о предыдущем статусе и дату/время смены статуса?